# freeing pointer passed to function where it was allocated

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I have a function where malloc is used to allocated a pointer and the pointer is passed to another function and thats passed to another function, where its used last.

My question is, can I call free in the final function for that allocated pointer? Or I need to call in the function where malloc is called.

Issue faced is , we see a memory leak since free for this allocated pointer is not coded till date. So my job is to fix the memory leak right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either, but not both. It is usually better for design to free memory in the same function where you allocate it.

Comment: If I free the pointer where its allocated, wont the pointer thats returned become NULL ? and I might ending corrupt pointer

Comment: You must free memory when you no longer need it. allocate - call function - free.

Comment: Right, so I need to free it once I have finished using it then

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you can free it anywhere, as long as you free it *exactly once* and after last use. The $1MM question is how you enforce this easily, in light of future use? Passing in pointers with ownership transfer semantics is in general bad. Returning pointers with allocation transfer is also bad, in general. If you design an API, consider abstracting the object being allocated and have allocate/free functions (eg. `allocate_widget` and `free-widget`). The API use should not know that the `widget` is allocated with `malloc()` and must be freed with `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call free in the final function for that allocated pointer, but it's not a good practice. Good practice is to call free function inside the function that owns the main pointer to the allocated memory (that may not be the function that allocates memory). 
Here's an example:

```
void func() 
{
    void* ptr = malloc(...); // ptr variable declared and initialized here.
    func2(ptr);
    func3(ptr);
    func4(ptr);
    free(ptr); // Free memory in function where ptr is declared.
}
```

Or, if `malloc` and `free` are incapsulated in higher-level functions:

```
void func() 
{
    void* ptr = allocateObject(...); // This function calls "malloc".
    func2(ptr);
    func3(ptr);
    func4(ptr);
    freeObject(ptr); // This function calls "free".
}
```

Consider also that C `free` function free dynamic allocated memory but don't change `ptr` variable value.
So if you're experiencing memory leaks a good practice is to set pointer variables to `NULL` after calling `free`. This way debugging the code you may immediately know if memory is allocated (`ptr != NULL`) or no (`ptr == NULL`)

```
if(ptr != NULL) 
{
    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
}
```